# Android Kiosk mode

Tags: android

Мы делаем игры для детей(маленьких), которые запускаются на телевизорах под управление андроид. Что бы ребенок не мог выйти из нашего лаунча я включил там Kiosk mode, но теперь нет возможности открывать через него игры, которые технически являются отдельными приложениями.

Может кто знает альтернативу такого подхода, или совет куда глянуть, что я мог пропустить?

Суть в том что бы сделать приложение рабочим столом для данного устройства, но и иметь возможность выйти в стандартную оболочку при наличии условного пароля)

Comment: Самый простой вариант - установить собственное приложение как лаунчер. Оно будет запускаться при старте системы и так далее. А стандартный лаунчер открывать прямым интентом по пакету. (после ввода пароля если так надо).

Comment: Я пробовал, но верхняя шторка остается, а как ее заблокировать отдельно не нашел решения(